# .htaccess remove .php extension

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have the following .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

it works fine on local but its not working on the web. Instead it shows 404 error. What may be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your live server? A root folder issue?

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file, or where are your .htaccess files, located? What url are you trying to access, and what file does the 404 message report it can't find? Things like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` have behaved weirdly for me in the past. You might want to consider something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$`

Comment: its in the root folder, I'm trying to access home.php,audio.php,photos.php files and the links i used in href are home,audio and photos respectively. Also 404 message reports "/domainname.com/audio was not found on this server"